# Where in Blender source code is code that draws transform rotate/resize black arrow visual indicators?

Tags: blender

I've been trying to find the piece of code that draws or initiates drawing of the double **black arrow visual indicators** that show up when transform rotate is executed by pressing `R` key (or resize with `S` key), visible here:
[image: Blender rotate black arrow indicator]

I've been stepping trough the code of the Rotate operator, various drawing functions etc., with no success. I suppose I do not have a good enough picture of the code structure.

I would appreciate it very much if someone could point me into the right direction.

Does someone know at least the **right terminology to look for?**

I'm using Blender 2.76 but I suppose insight into any version would be helpful.

(What I'm trying to do is to locate the point in code where decision is made whether to draw the indicator or not. I explained the "problem" in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78491/why-are-bpy-ops-transform-rotate-and-resize-missing-black-arrow-visual-indic/78503) question. The goal is to get it show always.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the place, not by stepping through the code but by browsing it, lol!

The function that draws the indicators is `drawHelpline()` and the check for the region being 'WINDOW' is done in `helpline_poll()`, both from transform.c file.

Actual decision is made in `wm_paintcursor_draw()` from wm_draw.c file which calls the `helpline_poll()` indirectly with `pc->poll(C)`.
The `wm_paintcursor_draw()` is called by `wm_method_draw_triple()` which in turn is called from `wm_draw_update()` which is called from `WM_main()`.

That answers my question.

**However**, that does not solve my actual problem because the active subwindow in these functions is the region from which the operator was executed - in my case the ToolShelf! It is because `cursor_warp()`, which I use to move the mouse in my operator, changes only the mouse pointer position and does not update anything else (i.e. does not update the active subwindow).
So, if I force `helpline_poll()` to return 1, it will draw the indicator only over the ToolShelf.
<del>The solution is to hack `WM_cursor_warp()` from wm_window.c to set `win->screen->subwinactive` to the correct window id, but that is really an ugly hack and not directly related to the question I asked here.</del>
The solution is to use modal timer operator to allow Blender to update the active subwindow, explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78491/why-are-bpy-ops-transform-rotate-and-resize-missing-black-arrow-visual-indic/78657#78657).

Comment: Sounds like you should report it to the bug tracker and see if the next release can be improved.

Comment: @Sambler, maybe. There was a `cursor_warp()` bugfix couple of releases ago that fixed the coordinates not being effective for operators, but that was literally two-lines fix. Don't remember if someone mentioned this GUI issue though. I will check it out.